# Writing a LIMIT subquery within my SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the following query which fetches active competitions for an organisation, but also aims to fetch the user that is in the lead - for each competition fetched.

The query currently works in that it fetches the competitions, however it currently fetches all the users and I would like to LIMIT 1 on the users fetched, using the SUM(activity_weight) you can see below.

The results come out like this (removed some results to make it easy to see) and in my case, I only want to fetch **John and Sally**, as they are the leaders of the competitions.

```
competitionId  compName  start_date  end_date  name  totalPoints
------------------------------------------------------------
123           First Comp   13-09-09  13-10-09  John    100
123           First Comp   13-09-09  13-10-09  Bob     50
431           Second Comp  13-05-04  13-10-05  Sally   500
431           Second Comp  13-05-04  13-10-05  Jessica 50
```

I understand that I must use some form of subquery to use the LIMIT, but having a problem nailing the syntax of it.

Any help is much appreciated! THANK YOU

```
  SELECT c.competitionId, c.name, c.start_date, c.end_date, a.userid, u.name, 
  u.profilePic , 
  SUM(activity_weight) AS totalPoints

  FROM activity_entries a INNER JOIN users1 u ON u.id = a.userid 
  INNER JOIN competitions c  ON c.competitionId = a.competitionId

  WHERE c.organisationId = '$organisation' AND c.start_date < now() AND c.end_date > now()  
  GROUP BY a.userid, c.competitionId ORDER BY c.id DESC, totalPoints DESC
```

Comment: Why c.id is in the fist position of the ORDER BY clause? I think it would be more logical to get the points in the first place, so you can cut the leader easily.

Comment: Because this query is used to print out active competitions on an organisations profile page in order of most recently created. Should I rethink it?

Comment: From my point of view, getting the most active competitions AND the leaders of each competition has to be done with two different queries. I assume the volume of data is not very big, so I wouldn't worry about performance, and it will keep the code clean.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is - using the active competitions query, I echo out some HTML, and within that HTML I'd like to have the winner for each competitions. How could I link those two queries so I can have the winner next to each competition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select * from
(select 
@rn:=if(@prv=competitionId  , @rn+1, 1) as rId,
@prv:=competitionId  as competitionId  ,
totalPoints,
your_other_columns
from (select * from ...)subquery
join
(select @prv:=0, @rn:=0)tmp
order by 
competitionId  , totalPoints desc) a
-- only top 2 ordered by points for every competition
where rid<=2

output:
rID  competitionId  compName  start_date  end_date  name  totalPoints
------------------------------------------------------------
 1      123           First Comp   13-09-09  13-10-09  John    100
 2      123           First Comp   13-09-09  13-10-09  Bob     50
 1      431           Second Comp  13-05-04  13-10-05  Sally   500
 2      431           Second Comp  13-05-04  13-10-05  Jessica 50
```

**change the last part to `where rid<=1` to select top 1**

Comment: Looks good, having a bit of trouble implementing it with my previous query, will keep trying. Thanks!

Comment: it's a pretty neat query worth saving. It basically starts a row count for every new value of CompetitionID, and you can order by whatever to get the top X for that competition ID. Implementation can be a bit PITA sometimes. you can use http://sqlformat.appspot.com/ for formatting the SQL to more readable shape

Comment: Ah ok! So in which part of that query should I fetch the competitions and in which part should I run the SUM()? Sorry for so many questions thanks man!

Comment: One conceptual question if you dont mind. This query now fetches active competitions that have results, so when a competition is first created, and no one has participated - it wont show up. Is there a way I could work that into the query too?

Comment: do a union on your subquery with a fixed value for participants to add a row

select .... from blabla 
union all 
select competition id, compname.... ,'nobody' as name, 0 as totalpoints from blabla

Comment: Could I also try using a LEFT JOIN which allows for null? i.e. competitions with no points registered yet.